# jquery mobile window.location.href Page jump error

Tags: javascript, jquery-mobile, cordova

help me!
I use `window.location.href` jump page but it is wrong 
code:

jquery

```js
function  onclick(){
     window.location.href="#main"
}
```

```html
<div data-role="page" id="login" class="ui-body-e">
<div data-role="content">   
        <input type="button" onClick="onclick()" value="ok"/>       
</div>
<div data-role="page" id="main" class="ui-body-e">
<div data-role="content">   
        <li><a href="#login">Login</a>      
</div>
</div>
```

> error: E:\Dockmate_hbx10\Dockmate\assets\www\  contains invalid path.
>   Sometimes can be the jump,This is why?

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to use a button as a link, you may consider the following solution:

Use:

```
<a data-role="button" href="#main"></a>
```

instead of:

```
<input type="button" value="ok"/>
```

So, your code would look like something like this:

**jQuery:** none

**HTML:**

```
<div data-role="page" id="login" class="ui-body-e">
    <div data-role="content">   
        <a data-role="button" href="#main"></a>
    </div>
</div>

<div data-role="page" id="main" class="ui-body-e">
    <div data-role="content">   
        <li><a href="#login">Login</a></li>   
    </div>
</div>
```

---

Another option would be to try the method `$.mobile.changePage()`:

**jQuery:**

```
$(function() {
    $("#my_button").click(function() {
        $.mobile.changePage("#main", { transition: "slideup"});
    });
});
```

**HTML:**

```
<div data-role="page" id="login" class="ui-body-e">
    <div data-role="content">   
        <input type="button" id="my_button" value="ok"/>       
    </div>
</div>

<div data-role="page" id="main" class="ui-body-e">
    <div data-role="content">   
        <li><a href="#login">Login</a></li>   
    </div>
</div>
```

For more information about the method `$.mobile.changePage()`, check the doc online: http://jquerymobile.com/test/docs/api/methods.html

Hope this helps.